# collect the azure activity log

Tags: azure, curl

I want to collect the azure activity log.

{ curl -X GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxx/providers/microsoft.insights/eventtypes/management/values?api-version=2015-04-01 }

this curl command gives an error.

> {"error":{"code":"AuthenticationFailed","message":"Authentication failed. The 'Authorization' header is missing."}}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error, seems you need to add your Authorization Token.

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer [TOKEN]" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxx/providers/microsoft.insights/eventtypes/management/values?api-version=2015-04-01
```

For more details, you could refer to this [link](https://medium.com/@mauridb/calling-azure-rest-api-via-curl-eb10a06127).